# Python Coding Help Needed, searching list by first letter of each word

Tags: python

Hi I am coding in Python and I have to Write a program that lets a user choose a letter. The program will then find all the words beginning with that letter in a list and print them out. It should also say how many words it found. Can anyone help I don't have a clue and an internet search turned up nothing.

Comment: This question is not suitable for SO in its current form. Do you know how to write a `for` loop that prints each word in a list of words?

Comment: You have to try to write some code and post it. We will help you then but no one will write the code for you. SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: @JoeR If you are bored you will :D

Comment: I did have some code I wrote that found a word In a list if it had the letter in the word anywhere but I didn't think I needed to post that as well, thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Long version:**

```
def num_words(word_list, letter):
    total = []
    for word in word_listlist:
        if ( word.startswith(letter) ):
            total.append(word)
    return total

new_list = ["hello","bring","http","bin"]

print(num_words(new_list,"h"))
print(len(num_words(new_list,"h")))
```

**Or even easier using list comprehension:**

```
[val for val in new_list if val.startswith("h")]
```

Comment: Since you are bored, try rewriting `num_words` in just one line of Python. If you are stuck, google for 'list comprehension'. Then you can collapse it further by making `num_words` a lambda.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire Thanks for the idea. At least learned something useful this way.